# CSS media queries to change UI control

Tags: css, media-queries

I was wondering if I could use media queries to render different UI control based on screen-size. I would like to use radio control to collect survey questions for desktops and tablets, and dropdown select control for mobiles, as using radio for mobiles clutters the screen.

Please help!

Comment: _I was wondering if I could use media queries..._ - yes, you can. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Put both dropdowns and radios in your html and hide them conditionally :

```
<input type="radio" name="myinput[]" value="value1" />
<input type="radio" name="myinput[]" value="value2" />
<select name="myinput">
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

CSS :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) { // adjust to desired width
    input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 421px) { // adjust to desired width
    select {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You could also use a custom class if you don't want this behaviour everywhere.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you're using a responsive grid framework, this functionality may already be baked in. In Boostrap, for example, you can use `visible-*`/`hidden-*` classes to only show/hide elements based on the breakpoints defined by your grid.